# Unable to create API after changing hostname in WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 GA Release

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, hostname

I have tried [changing hostname](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/#changing-the-api-m-hostname) in WSo2 API Manager 4.1.0 GA Release.

Below are the steps followed in `Windows OS 11`:

- Updated hostname in `<API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml`

[image: hostname]

- Generated a new key store, export the public certificate from the keystore, and import that self signed certificate to the client­-truststore.jks file also done.
- Hostname entry done in `/etc/hosts` and values like below
  `127.0.0.1 localhost dev.wso2.com`
- after made some changes in Carbon console as specified [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/) , i could able to access `publisher, devportal, admin and carbon` portal with host called `dev.wso2.com`

[image: publisher url]

- Certificate details shown like below from console URL

[image: certificate details]

- When restarting the server got below ERROR in wso2carbon.log even though console url is accessible with hostname.

  `ERROR - DBRetriever Error while executing the http client javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []`

Full Log:

```
    [2023-02-20 13:04:48,707]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 4 seconds...
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : tokenRevocation of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#tokenRevocation
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : keyManager of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#keyManager
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : cacheInvalidation of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#cacheInvalidation
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : asyncWebhooksData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#asyncWebhooksData
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : throttleData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#throttleData
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification
[2023-02-20 13:04:48,758]  INFO - JMSListener Started to listen on destination : throttleData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#throttleData
[2023-02-20 13:04:52,717]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 8 seconds...
[2023-02-20 13:05:00,746]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 16 seconds...
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,746]  WARN - APILoggerManager Failed retrieving /api-logging-configs from remote endpoint: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []. Retrying after 15 seconds.
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,746]  WARN - SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Failed retrieving /api-policies from remote endpoint: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []. Retrying after 15 seconds.
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,766]  WARN - SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Failed retrieving /apis?gatewayLabel=Default from remote endpoint: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []. Retrying after 15 seconds.
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,766]  WARN - SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Failed retrieving /application-policies from remote endpoint: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []. Retrying after 15 seconds.
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,767]  WARN - SubscriptionDataStore Failed retrieving webhooks subscription data from remote endpoint: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,767] ERROR - DBRetriever Error while executing the http client
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.executeHTTPRequest_aroundBody6(APIUtil.java:655) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.executeHTTPRequest(APIUtil.java:648) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.invokeService_aroundBody10(DBRetriever.java:215) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.invokeService(DBRetriever.java:196) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.retrieveAllArtifacts_aroundBody6(DBRetriever.java:128) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.retrieveAllArtifacts(DBRetriever.java:121) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAllAPIsAtGatewayStartup_aroundBody4(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:172) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAllAPIsAtGatewayStartup(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:156) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsAtStartup_aroundBody2(GatewayStartupListener.java:134) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsAtStartup(GatewayStartupListener.java:120) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsInGateway_aroundBody18(GatewayStartupListener.java:281) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsInGateway(GatewayStartupListener.java:270) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.access$0_aroundBody30(GatewayStartupListener.java:270) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.access$0(GatewayStartupListener.java:270) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener$AsyncAPIDeployment.run_aroundBody0(GatewayStartupListener.java:386) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener$AsyncAPIDeployment.run(GatewayStartupListener.java:383) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_291]
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,767]  WARN - SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Failed retrieving /application-key-mappings from remote endpoint: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []. Retrying after 15 seconds.
[2023-02-20 13:05:01,769] ERROR - InMemoryAPIDeployer Error deploying APIs to the Gateway
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.exception.ArtifactSynchronizerException: Error while executing the http client
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.retrieveAllArtifacts_aroundBody6(DBRetriever.java:141) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.retrieveAllArtifacts(DBRetriever.java:121) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAllAPIsAtGatewayStartup_aroundBody4(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:172) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAllAPIsAtGatewayStartup(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:156) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsAtStartup_aroundBody2(GatewayStartupListener.java:134) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsAtStartup(GatewayStartupListener.java:120) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsInGateway_aroundBody18(GatewayStartupListener.java:281) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.deployArtifactsInGateway(GatewayStartupListener.java:270) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.access$0_aroundBody30(GatewayStartupListener.java:270) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener.access$0(GatewayStartupListener.java:270) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener$AsyncAPIDeployment.run_aroundBody0(GatewayStartupListener.java:386) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayStartupListener$AsyncAPIDeployment.run(GatewayStartupListener.java:383) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_291]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.executeHTTPRequest_aroundBody6(APIUtil.java:655) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.executeHTTPRequest(APIUtil.java:648) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.invokeService_aroundBody10(DBRetriever.java:215) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.invokeService(DBRetriever.java:196) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.DBRetriever.retrieveAllArtifacts_aroundBody6(DBRetriever.java:128) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
```

and i couldn't able to create API in publisher post this hostname change in product.

[image: publisher]

Noticed below logs while creating API in publisher

```
    [2023-02-20 17:48:36,467]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 2 seconds...
[2023-02-20 17:48:38,485]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 4 seconds...
[2023-02-20 17:48:42,499]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 8 seconds...
[2023-02-20 17:48:50,512]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 16 seconds...
[2023-02-20 17:49:06,526]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 32 seconds...
[2023-02-20 17:49:38,536]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 64 seconds...
[2023-02-20 17:50:42,544]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 128 seconds...
```

deployment.toml:

```
[server]
#hostname = "localhost"
hostname = "dev.wso2.com"
#offset=0
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.shared_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2SHARED_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.tls]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "devwso2.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "dev.wso2.com"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.listener_profile]
#bind_address = "0.0.0.0"

#[keystore.primary]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.internal]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://dev.wso2.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://dev.wso2.com:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://dev.wso2.com:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://dev.wso2.com:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://dev.wso2.com:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://dev.wso2.com:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://dev.wso2.com:8021"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

[oauth.token_validation]
app_access_token_validity = -1
user_access_token_validity = -1
refresh_token_validity = -1

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.resource]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"


#[apim.analytics]
#enable = false
#auth_token = ""

[apim.analytics]
enable = true
config_endpoint = "https://analytics-event-auth.choreo.dev/auth/v1"
auth_token = "637e2cbb-64eb-4f1c-b48b-cd7bddf74b38"

#[apim.key_manager]
#service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"




[apim.key_manager]
enable_apikey_subscription_validation = true
#service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
service_url = "https://dev.wso2.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#[apim.idp]
#server_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}"
#authorize_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oauth2/authorize"
#oidc_logout_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oidc/logout"
#oidc_check_session_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oidc/checksession"

#[apim.jwt]
#enable = true
#encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
#claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
#convert_dialect = false
#header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
#signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
#enable_user_claims = true
#claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.ExtendedDefaultClaimsRetriever"

#[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
#revoke_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

#[apim.devportal]
#url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
[apim.devportal]
url = "https://dev.wso2.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true
#enable_anonymous_mode=true
#enable_cross_tenant_subscriptions = true
#default_reserved_username = "apim_reserved_user"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://dev.wso2.com:9611","tcp://dev.wso2.com:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://dev.wso2.com:9711","ssl://dev.wso2.com:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://dev.wso2.com:9611","tcp://dev.wso2.com:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://dev.wso2.com:9711","ssl://dev.wso2.com:9711"]
type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.17/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.17/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

#[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
#hostname = "localhost"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://dev.wso2.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[oauth.grant_type.token_exchange]
enable = true
allow_refresh_tokens = true
iat_validity_period = "1h"


[apim.sdk]
supported_languages = ["android", "java", "csharp", "dart", "groovy", "javascript", "jmeter", "perl", "php", "python", "ruby", "swift5", "clojure"]
```

how to resolve that `SSLPeerUnverifiedException ERROR` and why i am unable to create API in publisher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have generated a new certificate and it does not contain localhost as an alternative DNS, you are getting this issue. To overcome this issue, you can replace localhost values with dev.wso2.com.

You can add the following configuration to the deployment.toml and restart the server.

```
[apim.throttling] 
service_url = "https://dev.wso2.com:9443/services/"
```

Comment: Hi @Pubci
Be default below are the config looks like.
#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]. Do i need to make change in "throttle_decision_endpoints" ? or need to manually add new param "service_url" under the apim.throttling. please clarify on the same

Comment: These are commented configs. You can leave those as it is and add what I have provided

Comment: Hi @Pubci,
Thanks for your suggestion.
After adding the above mentioned line in deployment.toml file, ERROR gone and i could able to create API in publisher too.